# Change image interleave to BIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am working with [AVIRIS Classic data](https://aviris.jpl.nasa.gov/dataportal/) which has an interleave of BIP, or Band Interleaved by Pixel. I want to convert the datatype to BIL (Band Interleaved by Line). In the image processing language IDL, you can do this using the function [`CONVERT_DOIT`](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/CONVERT_DOIT.html), but this uses a proprietary software. Are there any python libraries that have a function to carry out this task?

Comment: May I ask what software needs BIL data? Most current software tends to want either BIP *"Band Interleaved by Pixel"* or planar data, i.e. *"Band Interleaved by Plane"*.

Comment: I need BIL for an algorithm my colleague wrote. One of the dependencies requires BIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am completely unfamiliar with AVIRIS data and its processing, so there may be much simpler or better methods of accessing it of which I am unaware. However, I found and downloaded a smallish sample from the linked website as follows:

[image]

Reading the `.hdr` file (which is ASCII fortunately), I was able to work out that the data are signed 16-bit integers, band-interleaved-by-pixel of 224 bands, and 735 samples/line and 2017 lines. So, I can then load the image and process it with `Numpy` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define datafile parameters
channels, samples, lines = 224, 735, 2017

# Load file and reshape
im = np.fromfile('f090710t01p00r11rdn_b_ort_img', dtype=np.int16).reshape(lines,samples,channels)
```

The data are signed integers in the range -32768...+32767, so if we add 32768 the data will be 0..65536 and then multiply by 255/65535 we should get a viewable, but not radiometrically correct, image to prove the reading from file:

```
# That's kind of all - just do crude scaling to show we have it correctly
a = (im.astype(np.float)+32768.0)*255.0/65535.0
```

Now select band 0, and save (using PIL, but we could use OpenCV or `tifffile`):

```
Image.fromarray(a[:,:,0].astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Presumably you can now arrange the data however you like with `Numpy` as we have read it successfully. So, say you want line 7 of band 4, you could use:

```
a[7,:,4]
```

Or line 0, all bands:

```
a[0,:,:]
```

---

If you wanted to make a false colour composite from 3 of the 224 bands, you can use `np.dstack()` like this - my bands were chosen at random:

```
FalseColour = np.dstack((a[...,37], a[...,164], a[...,200])).astype(np.uint8)

Image.fromarray(FalseColour).save('result.png')
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, AVIRIS, hyperspectral image processing, hyper-spectral, band-interleaved by pixel, by line, planar, interlace.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Using your workflow, I was able to get the data into the format I needed. Then I used the spectral library to save the image in BIL format.